# Question about keeping workload_identity_provider as secrets

Tags: github-actions, google-iam, google-secret-manager

Do we need to keep the `workload_identity_provider` and `service_account` as secrets when setting up [authentication](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth) via Workload Identity Federation from Github actions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend treating those values as secrets.

Both contain **sensitive** information. An attacker cannot do anything with just those pieces of information.

The `workload_identity_provider` contains the Project Number and Pool ID. Both are sensitive information but not secrets.

The `service account` email address is sensitive information but not a secret.